# Is my current implementation of message signing on AVR sufficient and correct?

Tags: hmac, sha256

I am currently implementing a fairly simple signing library (for my personal use) to verify the identity of packets sent with the [RF24Mesh](https://github.com/TMRh20/RF24Mesh/) library (using NRF24L01+) radios. Never made a flowchart but I've added one to clarify my current implementation. I'm using Atmel's ATMega328P to do all the calculations.

All devices have a list of unique MAC addresses of other nodes programmed in them. Then before sending the message the device just checks if it has a nonce that can be used to send the message. If not then it's requested. When there's nonce, [HMAC-SHA256](https://github.com/mysensors/Arduino/tree/development/libraries/MySensors/drivers/ATSHA204) library/implementation is used to include a hash of the data(+hmac+nonce) sent in the payload.

Now my question is, is my implementation secure in the way that it would be the only way to hit me with a wrench to turn on my TV than to forge packets to do the same?

[image: Signing process]

Do ask if something was left unclear.